# Debug a javascript function in visual studio code using liveserver extension while my local host(IIS) is occupied with another environment

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, iis, liveserver

i have a problem.

I wanna debug a function using visual studio code. I cant use the Debug Console with node.js because i wanted to use **window** object to detect which function are currently running, as i'm learning how to use **promise** object. Therefore, i need to launch a browser when debugging in visual studio code. How i'm going to do this is by using **Live Server** extension by **Ritwick Dey**.

When i run this extension, it opens a browser, **directed to localhost:5500**, and somehow tried to **download a file in my inetpub**, instead of running this functions i saved in another place(in my desktop, not in inetpub). I have a local environment using **IIS** for my work.

How do i make it work so **Live Server will run my functions instead of trying to download something from my existing environment**? Do i need to save my file inside inetpub, or close my existing environment in IIS first and add another one to cater for this live server?

Answer (score 0):

Orait. So the only thing i actually need to do is open another instance of vscode and open the test folder as workspace instead of using my work folder as workspace. Then run the live server.